# The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: .net, fileloadexception

I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It do not give me any hint of which file it's complaining about. How can I find the assembly that it complains about?

*(Yes, there are other questions about the same exception here at SO, but they do not answer my question)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely cause is the application is loading a different version of the assembly from somewhere you are not expecting.

There are a few ways to find out where assembly is loaded from. Best one is to use Sysinternal's [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which file it is loading before the error happens.

Comment: I've monitored with `ProcessMonitor`, but no `Load Image` seems to be off.

Answer (score 0):

You may check in Nuget Package Manager (VS2015) to see all the versions of assemblies used by your projects in solution.